# How to clear stack messages in Redis store?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I use Redis store in backend on Node.js and `push/subscrib` redis methods.

At next code are listened channels in Redis and send it all clients via socket.io.

```
_rPublic.on('pmessage', function (pattern, channel, data) {
       io.sockets.in(_getChannel(data)).emit(channel, _detectMessage(data));
});
```

How I can clean redis `channel` after sending data to all clients?
When I add a new data at the `same channel` I get previous messages on client from this channel.

Comment: I can suggest is problem in queue in socket.io